# Matplotlib graph not showing during While statement

Tags: python, selenium, matplotlib, while-loop

I'd like some help with my script.

It's purpose is to monitor the current URL in a browser and, if the URL changes, draw a network graph that shows how that domain relates to other domains in a database. It's based on the following loop:

- check if last_focus_domain is the same as the focus_domain
- if they differ, draw the graph then set the last_focus_domain as equal to the focus_domain, then set the focus_domain as the current domain from the current browser URL, then check again
- if they are the same, don't draw anything, set the focus_domain as the current domain from the current browser URL, then check again

What actually happens: the browser launches correctly and the if/else branching works fine (so the variables are updating from the browser) (see my print()s for monitoring). However, no graph is drawn when the script is running, and the handy display in PyCharm that shows one's variables does not update. Then when I close the script, the last graph that would have been drawn under proper operation is shown, and the variable display updates.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

```
# Prep

# Get Libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from pathlib import Path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from numpy import random as nprand
import tldextract
from time import sleep
import random

# Set data directory path
data_dir = Path('.') / 'data'

# Open Browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/oliver/Programs/chromedriver_linux64-87/chromedriver', service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=/home/oliver/driver.log"])

# Define the current URL, the current domain and the previous domain
focus = driver.current_url
ext = tldextract.extract(focus)
focus_domain = ext.domain + '.' + ext.suffix
last_focus_domain = focus_domain

# Main Loop
# Purpose: show the user a network graph that shows how their current page in browser relates to other domains in the database
# Function: 
# - check if the last domain is the same as the current domain
# - if they differ, draw the graph then set the last_focus_domain as equal to the focus_domain, then set the focus_domain as the current domain from the current browser URL, then check again
# - if they are the same, don't draw anything, set the focus_domain as the current domain from the current browser URL, then check again

while True:
    if last_focus_domain != focus_domain:
        #for monitoring
        print('if')
        # Build and Display Graph
        # Clear previous graph from plt display
        plt.clf()
        # Use a random seed to make sure we get the same visual 
        seed = 2
        nprand.seed(seed)
        random.seed(seed)
        # Define desired CSV columns
        header = 'Source,Target\n'
        # Open CSV database (first.csv), filter data with focus_domain and store filtered data (filtered.csv)
        with open(data_dir / 'scenarios' / 'first.csv', 'r') as f, open(data_dir / 'scenarios' / 'filtered.csv', 'w') as x: x.writelines(header), x.writelines(filter(lambda line: focus_domain in line, f))
        # Generate graph (G) with filtered data
        with open(data_dir / 'scenarios' / 'filtered.csv', 'rb') as y:
            # Skip header
            next(y)
            # Read edgelist format
            G = nx.read_edgelist(
                y,
                delimiter=",",
                # Create using directed graph
                create_using=nx.DiGraph,
                # Use Source and Target columns to define the nodes of our edges
                data=[('Source', str), ('Target', str)])
        # Define layout or shape of graph
        pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k=0.9)
        # Spring layout treats edges as springs that attract and nodes as repelling objects
        # Draw the two graphs of outbound and inbound links. Each has a different shape and color.
        nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=3, alpha=0.2, edge_color="#06D6A0", arrowsize=22)
        # Draw Nodes
        nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_color="#118AB2", node_shape="h", node_size=1000)
        # Draw the labels
        nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=8, font_weight="bold")
        # Add margins
        plt.gca().margins(0.1, 0.1)
        # Display the graph
        plt.show()
        # Set last_focus_domain as equal to focus_domain
        last_focus_domain = focus_domain
        # Get current browser URL/location
        focus = driver.current_url
        ext = tldextract.extract(focus)
        # GSet current domain (domain + suffix)
        focus_domain = ext.domain + '.' + ext.suffix
        sleep(1)
    else:
        #for monitoring
        print('else')
        # Set last_focus_domain as equal to focus_domain
        last_focus_domain = focus_domain
        # Get current browser URL/location
        focus = driver.current_url
        # Get current domain (domain + suffix)
        ext = tldextract.extract(focus)
        focus_domain = ext.domain + '.' + ext.suffix
        sleep(1)
    #Break condition
    if focus_domain == '2':
        break
```

Comment: Did you try replacing `sleep(...)` with `plt.pause(...)`?

Comment: Can you help me figure out why this was/drop me a link to learn more?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/rotate_axes3d_sgskip.html ?